# Remove checkbox visibility on list view items when onBackPressed

Tags: java, android

I am working on a note applications where i am showing check box items on the list views when it is long pressed. I need to remove the check box visibility when the user tries to go back when the check boxes are visible. How do i go about this?

```
public class NotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView mListNotes;
    NoteListAdapter na;
   private CheckBox mCheckBox;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);
        mListNotes = findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
        listViewLongClick();
    }

    private void listViewLongClick() {
        mListNotes.setLongClickable(true);
        mListNotes.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                for (int index = 0; index < parent.getChildCount(); ++index) {
                    View nextChild = (parent.getChildAt(index));
                     mCheckBox = nextChild.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                    mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mCheckBox.isShown()) {
mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.Gone); //i need to remove checkbox visibility here if already visible
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "when the user tries to go back"?

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isAnyItemChecked = false;

private void listViewLongClick() {
        mListNotes.setLongClickable(true);
        mListNotes.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                for (int index = 0; index < parent.getChildCount(); ++index) {
                    View nextChild = (parent.getChildAt(index));
                     mCheckBox = nextChild.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                    mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                isAnyItemChecked = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


       @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if(isAnyItemChecked) {

               //repopulate adapter and attach to list view, so all items will be unchecked
               return;
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Any help on how to properly set check boxes on all list view items when one is long clicked?